# Ad accounts missing data in Facebook Marketing API call

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to get a full list of all ad accounts for a Facebook business using the PHP Business SDK v3.1.

I've tried this:

```
$business = new \FacebookAds\Object\Business('1234567890');
```

But all of the ad accounts in that list have the values set to null. Why is that?

```
array:57 [
      "account_id" => null
      "account_status" => null
      "age" => null
      "agency_client_declaration" => null
      "amount_spent" => null
      "attribution_spec" => null
      "balance" => null
      "business" => null
      "business_city" => null
      "business_country_code" => null
      "business_name" => null
      "business_state" => null
      "business_street" => null
      "business_street2" => null
      "business_zip" => null
      "capabilities" => null
      "created_time" => null
      "currency" => null
      "disable_reason" => null
      "end_advertiser" => null
      "end_advertiser_name" => null
      "extended_credit_invoice_group" => null
      "failed_delivery_checks" => null
      "funding_source" => null
      "funding_source_details" => null
      "has_migrated_permissions" => null
      "has_page_authorized_adaccount" => null
      "id" => null
      "io_number" => null
      "is_attribution_spec_system_default" => null
      "is_direct_deals_enabled" => null
      "is_in_middle_of_local_entity_migration" => null
      "is_notifications_enabled" => null
      "is_personal" => null
      "is_prepay_account" => null
      "is_tax_id_required" => null
      "line_numbers" => null
      "media_agency" => null
      "min_campaign_group_spend_cap" => null
      "min_daily_budget" => null
      "name" => null
      "offsite_pixels_tos_accepted" => null
      "owner" => null
      "partner" => null
      "rate_limit_reset_time" => null
      "rf_spec" => null
      "show_checkout_experience" => null
      "spend_cap" => null
      "tax_id" => null
      "tax_id_status" => null
      "tax_id_type" => null
      "timezone_id" => null
      "timezone_name" => null
      "timezone_offset_hours_utc" => null
      "tos_accepted" => null
      "user_role" => null
      "user_tos_accepted" => null
    ]
```